# Function returining function

Tags: javascript

//The fn is  a function calling ajax request to get data

```
function fn(onSuccess, onError, args ){
}
```

//I need to write retry function which calls fn function for API call. the max attempt will be 5. If attempt exceeds I need to call the onError function.

//Signature of retry

```
function retry(fn,attempt, onSuccess, onError, args){

}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? All you are showing is wireframes.

Comment: you may need to read about [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Hi Snehal and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour [ see the (?)  button at top right] and visit the help center to learn about asking questions. Following guidelines for "how to ask a good question" and "how to create a minimal and complete example" will help avoid so many down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exercise (or your teacher) is probably expecting a recursive function - one that increments the `attempt` parameter on each call to `retry` and calls `retry`'s `onError` argument if the recursion depth exceeds the maximum number of attempts.

The first design note is that `retry` will not pass its `onError` argument directly to `fn`, but will instead create and pass an intermediary error function that checks how many times `fn` has been called and recursively calls `retry` if the maximum count has not been exceeded.

The following code example is *not recursive* and the `attempt` parameter could have been an internal variable. It processes `args` as meaning "any number of trailing arguments". If the question is about homework, please write an answer appropriate to what you have been learning.

```
function retry(fn, attempt, onSuccess, onError, args){
    const MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
    let fnArgs = [
        onSuccess,
        function( error) {  // fn's onError argument
            if( attempt > MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                onError( error);
            }
            else {
                attempt += 1;
                fn.apply( null, fnArgs); // next attempt
            }
        }
    ];
    let moreArgs = Array.from( arguments).slice( 4);
    fnArgs = fnArgs.concat( moreArgs);
    fn.apply( null, fnArgs);  // first attempt;
}
```